# Hiding foreign entity classes from EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I have a Java EE web application and a custom realm (authentication module) for Glassfish 4 (see [GlassFish Application Development Guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-development-guide.pdf), II 4-6 "Creating a Custom Realm"). Both of them are using JPA, with subtle differences.

### Custom realm

```
<persistence-unit name="AuthPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/AuthDB</jta-data-source>
    <class>auth.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

- `auth.User` is a technical entity that contains authentication-specific data
- `EntityManager` is created with Persistence API (since no injection is available for realms)
- `META-INF/orm.xml` is used to define mappings (no `@Entity` annotations at all)
- the module is packaged as JAR and deployed to `$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib`

### Application

```
<persistence-unit name="AppPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/AppDB</jta-data-source>
    <class>app.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

- `app.User` is a business entity
- `EntityManager` is injected with @PersistenceContext
- both `@Entity` annotations (for basic mappings) *and* `META-INF/orm.xml` file (for customization) are used
- application is packaged and deployed in the standard way.

Upon application deployment, an exception is thrown:

```
Severe:   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [AppPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7237] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Entity name must be unique in a persistence unit. Entity name [User] is used for the entity classes [app.User] and [auth.User].
```

Seems like `AppPU` persistence unit somehow discovers entities from `auth.*` package (via orm.xml?) I don't want to alter entity names because it will break existing JPQL queries. How can I isolate the modules so that `AppPU` ignores foreign `orm.xml` and doesn't look into `auth.*` package for entities?

P.S. As you may have noticed, `EclipseLink` version is `2.6.0` - I've upgraded it manually. `Eclipse 2.5.2` shipped with `GlassFish 4.1` gave the same exception.

Comment: Could you use the standard JDBCRealm? If you can maybe you could use  database views that conforms the requeriments of GlassFish, (usersname and password in a view and username and role in other).
without touching your database tables.

Comment: @Ismael_Diaz, the whole point of creating custom realm was to implement a non-standard authentication scheme (one-time passwords).

Comment: Is your orm.xml file being picked up by your "AppPU" persistence unit?  How do you have them packaged?  The issue will be in Glassfish, as it controls what the JPA provider sees as being apart of the container managed persistence context.

Comment: @Chris, the problem is indeed caused by GlassFish classloading model and orm.xml disposition - please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've figured out what exactly happens.

According to [GlassFish Application Deployment Guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-deployment-guide.pdf) (C-13),

> the web module follows the standard class loader
>   delegation model and delegates to its parent class loader first before
>   looking in the local class loader.

This is the default behavior which can be controlled with `<class-loader>` element of `glassfish-web.xml`. EclipseLink tries to process *each and every* `META-INF/orm.xml` it finds on classpath, and thus, picks that of the custom realm first. Even if application's `orm.xml` contains `<xml-mapping-metadata-complete/>`, it doesn't play a role, as `auth.*` classes are already added to the persistence unit.

There are two solutions for the problem (beside renaming entities):

1. Use `<class-loader delegate="false"/>` in `glassfish-web.xml`;
2. if the above is not acceptable ("for a web
   module that accesses EJB components or that acts as a web service client
   or endpoint" - Application Deployment Guide), rename custom realm's `META-INF/orm.xml` to something else and reflect it in `persistence.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

From the book Pro JPA2

> **xml-mapping-metadata-complete**
>
> When the xml-mapping-metadata-complete element is specified, all
>   annotations in the entire persistence unit will be ignored, and only
>   the mapping files in the persistence unit will be considered as the
>   total set of provided metadata. **Only entities, mapped superclasses,
>   and embedded objects that have entries in a mapping file will be added
>   to the persistence unit.** .....

```
<entity-mappings> 
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
         <xml-mapping-metadata-complete/> 
    </persistence-unit-metadata> ...
</entity-mappings>
```

Add the above to your orm.xml.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help. First of all I made sure that `META-INF/orm.xml` gets processed (it does indeed - renaming an entity works as intended). Then I thought it might be an EclipseLink bug and manually upgraded it to most recent version - that didn't work either, the exception is still present.